# No response from jsonArray request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Well long story short i face this kind of problem, Im trying to send volley request to my server, which responds with json array:

```
{
    "images": [{
        "product_serial_num": "1",
        "product_title": "Abbadon",
        "product_img": "http://1.2.3.4/android/uploads/1.jpg",
        "product_price": "750",
        "product_description": "The destroyer"
    }]
}
```

but no matter what i tried i still get Volley response error, my volley request:

```
  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(MY_URL ,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                     //parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

the weird thing that with volley string request it does work, only the array mess things for me.

EDIT:

how ever this way i do get my array using feed:

```
private void getData() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

//Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
//This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
//This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_INDEX + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Response Json is JSONObject not JSONArray.

Use `JsonObjectRequest` of volley instead of `JsonArrayRequest`

Comment: object and string both work, only array doesnt

Comment: Because response type is JSONObject

Comment: try @vinoth12594 ansewer

Comment: Change url method type POST or GET

Comment: i tried this way with get req and sending some paramter to the url, it gave me back jsonArray.

Comment: The response is an **object with an array inside** and *not* an array alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code, Change **JsonArrayRequest** to **JsonObjectRequest**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, MY_URL, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //parseData to parse the json response
                parseData(response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**Array Response**

```
"images": [{
    "product_serial_num": "1",
    "product_title": "Abbadon",
    "product_img": "http://1.2.3.4/android/uploads/1.jpg",
    "product_price": "750",
    "product_description": "The destroyer"
}]
```

**Object Response**

```
{
"images": [{
    "product_serial_num": "1",
    "product_title": "Abbadon",
    "product_img": "http://1.2.3.4/android/uploads/1.jpg",
    "product_price": "750",
    "product_description": "The destroyer"
}]
}
```

Comment: it doing the job, but why cant i use array req?

Comment: Your response is object not a array

Comment: sec ill show u diffrent snippet, with arrayReq what the difference?

Comment: added in EDIT, with feed

Comment: One json request you cannot get two type of response.

Comment: Change your response to array formate. Check my update code

Comment: KK ty pal, ill swap to object again